# Script to check Windows version and then do action on only version 10.0 (2016 or greater)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am developping a script with the goal to do a action only on Windows version 10.0 or greater.

i have tried to launch my code but the both 2 actions are performed, on Win 2016 the batch should normally execute only the program related to goto in the if/else

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j

echo %version%
pause
if "%version%" geq "10.0" ( goto :AddWinDefenderExclusion )
else ( goto :NoWinDefenderExclusion )

:AddWinDefenderExclusion
echo Windows Defender Exclusion will be added


:NoWinDefenderExclusion
echo No Windows Defender Exclusion to add (Not a Windows 2016 or greater)

endlocal
```

Can you please help me to achieve the version control then the proper action ?

Comment: 1. you need to place `goto :EOF` before `:NoWinDefenderExclusion` in order for execution not to continue unexpectedly; 2. The operator `geq` in `if "%version%" geq "10.0"` would consider `9.0` as greater than `10.0` since this is string comparison (since there are non-numeric characters like `.` and `"`); you should do `set "VERSION=%%i"` and then `if %VERSION% gtr 10` to have a numeric comparison, so `10` is considered as greater than `9` now (you could even use `set /A "VERSION=%%i+0"` instead of `set "VERSION=%%i"` to ensure `%VERSION%` is never empty)...

Comment: 3. the `if`/`else` syntax is wrong -- type `if /?` to learn how it works; in this situation you could even omit `else` and just do `goto :NoWinDefenderExclusion`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `goto :eof` ([[SS64]: GOTO](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)) at the end of *:AddWinDefenderExclusion*, and *:NoWinDefenderExclusion* labels. Technically, you don't have to do this for the last one (as it will reach *eof* anyway), however you should do it:

- For consistency
- You won't run into trouble if adding other instructions after it

*script.bat*:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal

for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do (
    set VERSION_MAJ=%%i
    set VERSION_MIN=%%j
)

set MAJ_REQ=10
set MIN_REQ=0

echo %VERSION_MAJ%.%VERSION_MIN%

if %VERSION_MAJ% gtr %MAJ_REQ% (
        goto :AddWinDefenderExclusion
) else if %VERSION_MAJ% equ %MAJ_REQ% (
    if %VERSION_MIN% geq %MIN_REQ% (
        goto :AddWinDefenderExclusion
    )
)
goto :NoWinDefenderExclusion

goto :eof

:AddWinDefenderExclusion
    echo Windows Defender Exclusion will be added
    pause
    goto :eof

:NoWinDefenderExclusion
    echo No Windows Defender Exclusion to add (Not a Windows 2016 or greater)$
    pause
    goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this easiest using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic):

```bat
@Echo Off
WMIC OS Where "Version Like '__.%%'" Get Status 2> NUL | Find "Status" > NUL && (
    Echo Windows Defender Exclusion will be added
) || Echo No Windows Defender Exclusion to add [Not Windows 2016 or greater]
Pause
```

If your script is simply not for any version of Windows before Windows 10, then this would probably work better:

```bat
@Echo Off
WMIC OS Where "Version Like '__.%%'" Get Status 2> NUL | Find "Status" > NUL || Exit /B
Echo Windows Defender Exclusion will be added & Pause
```

*The last line is obviously where you provide your own code.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

Here is my final code:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do (
    set VERSION=%%i
)

if %version% GEQ 10 (
    goto :ADDEXCLUSION
) else (
    goto :NOEXCLUSION
)

:ADDEXCLUSION
echo ADDEXCLUSION
pause
goto :eof

:NOEXCLUSION
echo NOEXCLUSION
pause
goto :eof
```

I think if `GEQ` can be used only with numbers,
without quotes it compare numbers and with quotes both on the variable `%version%` and value it compare string. In my case my script check for the version number, *(first 2 digits)*.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Yes, good catch with the strings! I didn't test my code thoroughly. I modified my version so correctly works (and also makes use of both version numbers).